# When a Rishi is associated with a mantra, does it mean anything more than he/she is the author of the mantra?

Tags: rishi, author

for example the dhyana shloka of Vishnu Sahasra Nama says

> Asya shree vishno divya sahasranama sthotra maha-mantrasya, shree vedavyaso
> bhagavan rishih

Similarly, each mandala/group of Rig Vedic verses has a Rishi associated with it.